# Как сделать копирование файла во все папки в директории? C++

Tags: c++, windows, файловая-система

Мне надо написать часть программы на c++, которая будет копировать один файл из директории программы во все папки другой директории, сам не знаю вообще как это сделать, думаю можно через winapi

Comment: Для начала внимательно читаем [man fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [man fread](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) (fwrite описана там же), [man opendir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [man readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) и [man stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html). / Надеюсь после этого идеи появятся

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно". В скобках замечу, что некоторые, увы, даже не представляют, что в Windows есть командная строка, которая умеет много гитик...

Ну, например, скопировать файл `x.y` в каждый подкаталог каталога `D:\Dest` - в командной строке Windows -

```
for /R D:\Dest /D %f in (*.*) do copy x.y %f\
```

Так что программа на C++ -

```
int main()
{
    system("for /R D:\\Dest /D %f in (*.*) do copy x.y %f\\");
}
```

Нет, конечно, если нужны именно шашечки, то...

**Update**

На случай пробелов в именах в командной строке Windows предусмотрены кавычки - типа,

```
for /R "D:\Dest i nation" /D %f in (*.*) do copy x.y "%f\"
```

Напомню также на всякий случай, во избежание новых уточнений, что в строках С/С++ кавычки экранируются...

```
system("for /R \"D:\\Dest i nation\" /D %f in (*.*) do copy x.y \"%f\\\"");
```

Comment: Что, для кого-то это оказалось таким откровением, что решил минус поставить? :)

Comment: А если у меня в пути есть пробелы то как сделать? А так проверил на пути без пробелов и все работает

Comment: А как обычно в командной строке в таких случаях, взять в кавычки не догадались?... `for /R G:\Test /D %f in (*.*) do copy 1-2.jpg "%f\"`?

Comment: Я знаю про то что в cmd нужны кавычки но как в c++ сделать не знал. Спасибо!